# Ruby: Call multiple end points / Nested POST api calls

Tags: ruby, api, rest, post

I have ruby code where I use POST to make a REST API call to 2 end points. I would like to combine them to make a single call
I would like my api call `to org_a_request` and `org_b_request` in sequence

```
post '/REST/org/a' do
@code, @message, @data = org_a_request params
done

post '/REST/org/b' do
 @code, @message, @data = org_b_request params
done
```

how can I make it as just 1 end point instead of calling both a and b? Can I call both of them like shown below?

```
post '/REST/org/c' do
  post '/REST/org/a'
  post '/REST/org/b'
done
```

or should it be like?

```
post '/REST/org/c' do
   '/REST/org/a'
   '/REST/org/b'
done
```

Comment: You have to actually perform two posts, right, you are just looking for a cleaner way to handle the post-processing, aka you will have to do the same error-handling for both cases? There is no way (standard) to combine POST to multiple urls in one go. You probably have a specific use-case, posting to a main and fallback server? Doing a broadcast? Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want that both the above /a & /b request goes to the same action. We can do it that way

```
post '/REST/org/a', to: '/REST/org/c'
post '/REST/org/b', to: '/REST/org/c'
```

Now both of these requests will go to the same action i-e "/REST/org/c"

Comment: I didn't want them to redirect to c. I want a single call c which has to 1st execute a and then execute b